# How do I allow non www urls?

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex. How do I change it to allow non-www addresses as well?

```
if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$link))
{
    echo '<label style="color:#fff">Sorry, your link is not in a valid address format.</label><br>';
    $error = 1;
}
```

I'm really bad at regex :(

Comment: Change `www\.` to `(?:www\.)?`.

Comment: @stribizhev no, current regex also allows non www. addresses/.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Check [this](https://ideone.com/kxX5dj) (false) vs. [this code](https://ideone.com/Xg75w3) (true). Amy, does it work as you expect?

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev that works I think :)

Comment: @AmyNeville: you should reformulate your requirements cause it's a bit unclear: "allow non-www adresses" and you use a negative condition. Note that your actual pattern allows already addresses with `www.` and without. Other thing, when you need to test an url, `parse_url` is your best friend, not regexes.

Comment: You can also use `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  just need to specify that `www\.` subpattern is *optional*.

To make a subpattern optional, you can place it into a non-capturing group and set a `?` quantifier after it. Thus, change `www\.` to `(?:www\.)?`.

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Xg75w3)

```
$link = "google.com";
if (!preg_match('/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|(?:www\.)?)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i',$link))
{ //                                       ^^^     ^^ - OPTIONAL GROUP
    echo '<label style="color:#fff">Sorry, your link is not in a valid address format.</label><br>';
    $error = 1;
}
else echo "Good link!"; // => Good link!
```

Comment: No problem. You could also use an empty alternstive there, but since it is not Python it is more effecient to use optional groups.